# Select one fixed line and several arbitrary

Tags: mysql

I have a table with many lines. I need select several (no more than three) lines with certain values and one more. Moreover, need `ORDER BY id DESC` and required line position before other. Example:

```
id | name | group
-----------------
1  | One  | null
2  | Two  | null
3  | Three| 2
4  | Four | 3
5  | Five | 1
6  | Six  | 2
```

I need lines with `group` == 2 (no more than three) and line with `id` == 2. Result:

```
id | name | group
-----------------
2  | Two  | null
3  | Three| 2
6  | Six  | 2
```

Line with `id` == 2 must be selected, other lines - no more than three. If I use `WHERE id = 2 OR group = 2 LIMIT 4` than if exist more than 4 lines with `group` == 2, then required line with `id` == 2 not selected.

How solve the problem in one SQL-request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `UNION`. Also note that `group` is a reserved word for MySQL.

```
SELECT aa.* 
FROM (
    SELECT id, firstname, lastname
    FROM user
    WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
    LIMIT 2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT id, firstname, lastname
    FROM user
    WHERE id = 5

) AS aa
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_name where id=2 
union all 
select * from table_name where group=2
```